# Old TLS1.0 clients cannot connect to Google App Engine on Custom Domain

Tags: ssl

We have a Google App Engine project that is setup to work over a custom domain on HTTPS (Using Google managed SSL certs). For most part it is working fine e.g. on Chrome and other modern browsers but NOT for some old TL1.0 clients where it is failing the handshake.

The problem seems with **ghs.googlehosted.com** GFE servers. AppEngine GFEs on **appspot-preview.l.google.com** work fine for these clients.

Here is an example log with openssl, connecting to api.my-project.com

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ghs.googlehosted.com:443 -msg

CONNECTED(00000005)
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0139], ClientHello
    01 00 01 35 03 03 82 73 d6 6c 32 b7 84 f3 30 57
    8f 98 a7 6e e7 c2 f5 b8 be f4 29 55 41 25 35 ab
    56 51 3c 1e b9 e3 00 00 98 cc 14 cc 13 cc 15 c0
    30 c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00
    6b 00 6a 00 39 00 38 ff 85 00 c4 00 c3 00 88 00
    87 00 81 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00
    9d 00 3d 00 35 00 c0 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00
    32 00 be 00 bd 00 45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0
    25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 ba 00 41 c0
    11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08 00
    16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15 00 12 00 09 00
    ff 01 00 00 74 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00
    3a 00 38 00 0e 00 0d 00 19 00 1c 00 0b 00 0c 00
    1b 00 18 00 09 00 0a 00 1a 00 16 00 17 00 08 00
    06 00 07 00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13 00
    01 00 02 00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00 00
    0d 00 26 00 24 06 01 06 02 06 03 ef ef 05 01 05
    02 05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03 ee ee ed ed 03 01 03
    02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03
140735490237384:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s23_lib.c:124:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
```

It works connecting to my-project.appspot.com

```
$ openssl s_client -connect appspot-preview.l.google.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.appspot-preview.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.appspot-preview.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3166 bytes and written 444 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 7C3AAFD46B8D8C8C95F336DEAFFEAB0950B61A01DE9CCD33BC1B4E00B8778ACA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: F796ECD4CA06D7B3FD8888F5B74AA70C22846CCD207AFA9BC3686AD53E3CBAEA7E2535B9051C0CE2EB96CBA80090CD14
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 00 cf 37 1b ad 9e 5d e3-33 ca 1f 1a 53 78 e0 1b   ..7...].3...Sx..
    0010 - 9a 7b fe 86 70 da 77 ee-b6 a4 2d 0e 5d 57 c4 b0   .{..p.w...-.]W..
    0020 - 5e 3a f3 37 65 d1 bb c3-9f 47 0c e9 05 fc c0 6b   ^:.7e....G.....k
    0030 - 26 ed a2 27 dc 18 17 88-79 70 4f e4 92 a0 b7 fa   &..'....ypO.....
    0040 - b6 91 6e c0 7f c6 6e cc-35 81 02 5b 9d 4c 66 6f   ..n...n.5..[.Lfo
    0050 - 6e 5b d2 7e c5 8f bb 14-70 a8 dd 9b cb ff 50 07   n[.~....p.....P.
    0060 - 0f 9c 86 f6 4a d3 bd c7-20 26 2a b6 c3 f7 52 1e   ....J... &*...R.
    0070 - ce 1d 8e 77 be 65 d6 41-44 c8 9a 30 31 29 66 93   ...w.e.AD..01)f.
    0080 - 15 fc 76 f2 6a c5 68 92-23 96 d5 47 50 92 04 e0   ..v.j.h.#..GP...
    0090 - 6a de d4 77 b7 bb 02 cf-fd fe 75 71 13 2c c7 34   j..w......uq.,.4
    00a0 - 47 48 f3 fa a2 fc ef 7d-7a bd b9 94 8e 40 06 c6   GH.....}z....@..
    00b0 - a3 55 56 ec af 29 77 27-7f 40 98 4e ef 0b dc 54   .UV..)w'.@.N...T
    00c0 - 6d 8f d1 93 8f 96 2d c2-79 42 1f 4a 7b f4 d6 d9   m.....-.yB.J{...
    00d0 - e7 f0 d1 5a 83                                    ...Z.

    Start Time: 1526935566
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

Comment: Are you sure `ghs.googlehosted.com` speaks TLS at all? if so, try to add SNI. See also this thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg89202.html

Comment: ghs.googlehosted.com must speak TLS since its cname for my custom domain and I can certainly connect to it over https from any modern browser.

Comment: Many online scanners can not connect to it at all and say it does not speak TLS. You probably then absolutely need SNI. See the `-servername` option of `openssl`.

Comment: Yup I think SNI is needed, with -servername option openssl does connect to ghs.googlehosted.com. Unfortunately our old IoT clients seem to not support SNI so I need to figure out how to get that working on server side (without ghs.googlehosted.com). thanks a lot @PatrickMevzek

Comment: @AbhijitKalamkar did you figure this out? I have a fleet of ublox modem based IoT clients that do not support SNI and since May this year they have started failing connecting to AppEngine by TLS. Thought this might be related (we're not on a custom domain, but google might have started to change something that requires it anyway on *.appspot.com)